# Why does an executable still run despite changes to checksum, or changes to data section without new checksum?

Tags: windows, pe, c#, reassembly

I have a "Hello World" console app compiled with Flat Assembler. The size of the executable is 2048 bytes and the checksum is 0x3797.

**Questions:**

Does it matter if I make changes to the data section and minor change to code section of the executable while maintaining the same checksum?

Not really changing the opcode, just inserting different `input.Length` (length of null-terminated text string in data section)

```
     push 0xfffffff5 // - 11
     call DWORD PTR ds:0x40304c // .idata [GetStdHandle]
     push 0x0
     push 0x401014
     push [input.Length]
     push 0x401000 // .data
     push eax
     call DWORD PTR ds:0x403050 // .idata [WriteConsole]
     push 0x0
     call DWORD PTR ds:0x0403048 // .idata [ExitProcess]
```

Why does it still run even though I use different checksum?
For example, it still run even if I change the checksum to 0x995A or 0x5A99.

I use `ImageHlp.dll` to compute the checksum as summarized below:

```
int HeaderSum = 0;
int CheckSum = 0;
IntPtr ptrHeaderSum=Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
Marshal.WriteInt32(ptrHeaderSum, HeaderSum);
IntPtr ptrCheckSum = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(int));
Marshal.WriteInt32(ptrCheckSum, CheckSum);
UInt32 status= ImageHlp.MapFileAndCheckSumA(@"D:\19_02_21.exe", ptrHeaderSum, ptrCheckSum);

Console.WriteLine(status);
CheckSum = Marshal.ReadInt32(ptrCheckSum);
Console.WriteLine(CheckSum);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrHeaderSum);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrCheckSum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PE checksum is only checked for drivers by the kernel, for the user-mode binaries it's optional. As mentioned [in the doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/imagehlp/nf-imagehlp-mapfileandchecksuma):

> Checksums are required for kernel-mode drivers and some system DLLs.
>   The linker computes the original checksum at link time, if you use the
>   appropriate linker switch. For more details, see your linker
>   documentation.

The linker option is [`/RELEASE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/release-set-the-checksum):

> The /RELEASE option sets the Checksum in the header of an .exe file.
>
> The operating system requires the Checksum for device drivers. Set the
>   Checksum for release versions of your device drivers to ensure
>   compatibility with future operating systems.
>
> The /RELEASE option is set by default when the /SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE
>   option is specified.